# SQL: reading from csv file as part of a larger sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to read a csv into SQL without importing the file with a separate query. I do not have writing permissions so I can't import files or create tables.

What I was trying to do is something like this:

```
Select * 
From path_to_file/myfile.csv T1
inner join a_schema.a_table T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Edit 1: What SQL I'm using

```
select * from v$version

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Edit 2:
I tried creating a temporary table:

```
create table #Temp
( ID VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  Col2 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  )
```

But I get this error:

```
dentifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
```

Edit 2.1:

tried this instead:

```
create global temporary table Temp ...
```

and got insufficient privileges error.

Comment: Which database are you using (MySQL, SQL Server) ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL server (on oracle sql developer)

Comment: Can you read the entire table into a local table?  Then it wouldn't matter how many queries you need.

Comment: You can use sql loader to load csv files

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for clarifying - in my younger days, this was never possible - Oracle tools on Oracle DB only, Microsoft tools on SQL Server only ... :-)

Comment: You seem to be confused about which database product you are using - from your last edit it is Oracle not SQL Server - and are trying to use syntax and features that are not available. If you can't create a normal table (for SQL\*Loader) or external table, you could read the file line by line into a collection, *if* the CSV file is on the database server, somewhere Oracle can see it, and you have permissions on an Oracle directory object pointing to that location. Otherwise you're going to have to do some manual manipulation of the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Oracle.

As I understand you want to obtain data in oracle database without permissions on creating table or import something.

I see 2 ways to do it

1) you may try to create view with your own data (if you have `grant create view`)

```
 create or replace view as 
 select cvs_val1,cvs_val2 ...
```

2) create clob in plsql bloc and try to load data into lob separating data by 32767 chars. Or if you have some IDE load lob as param of test window. For instance PL\SQL Developer allow it. 
And use it lob as raw data to get something.

```
variable :l_clob clob; 
:l_clob := 'CVS_col1, CVS_col2'... -- row1;
:l_clob := :l_clob||chr(13)||chr(10)||'CVS_col1, CVS_col2'... -- row2;
...

declare 

begin
  <do something with data for instance create view here>
end;
/
```

the both ways are twisted

And last just for information good way is to create external table. It work if you have permission to create table and access to some oracle directory on a disc

```
CREATE TABLE EXTERNAL_CVS_TABLE_1
(
  C1   VARCHAR2(4000),
  C2   VARCHAR2(4000),
  C3   VARCHAR2(4000)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY SOME_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       (records delimited BY newline
        fields
            terminated BY ','
            optionally enclosed BY '"'
            lrtrim
            missing field VALUES are NULL
      )
     LOCATION ('my_cvs_file.csv')
  );
```